# JApplet loading problem

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I want to convert an java application to applet, but I an having problems to load it in the browser I presume this is because of the package.

```
package com.applet;

import java.applet.Applet;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
//import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AppletDriver extends Applet {

    //Called when this applet is loaded into the browser.
    public void init() {
        //Execute a job on the event-dispatching thread; creating this applet's GUI.
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    CleanerPanel cFrame = new CleanerPanel();
                    add(cFrame); 
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code I am using to call the applet when I run it in Eclipse it is working.
this is the html code:

```
<applet archive="app.jar" code="bin/com/applet/AppletDriver.class" width=350 height=200>
</applet>
```

the app.jar is in the main dir of the eclipse project any suggestions ?

error from browser java console:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bin/com/applet/AppletDriver (wrong name: com/applet/AppletDriver)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bin/com/applet/AppletDriver (wrong name: com/applet/AppletDriver)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `bin\` from the start of the `code` attribute value, and use `/` instead of `\` (we're not in Washington anymore). If the jar is in a directory named `bin` then you'll need to use `archive="bin/app.jar"`.

Actually looking at the stack trace, the jar has been constructed incorrectly. The class file should be in a directory `com/applet`, not `bin/com/applet`.